# bash ssh warning on Ubuntu when connect to raspberry: setlocale: LC_ALL: cannot change locale (en_US.UTF-8)

Tags: bash, ubuntu, ssh, raspberry-pi, locale

First of all, I would like to tell you that I have tried many solutions for my problem, but none of them helped me. (I tried for example this: http://ubuntuforums.org/showthread.php?t=1346581 and this(http://ubuntuforums.org/showthread.php?t=1346581) too)

My problem is that when I try to connect to my Raspberry pi2 using ssh, I got the following messages:

```
Linux raspberrypi 3.18.7-v7+ #755 SMP PREEMPT Thu Feb 12 17:20:48 GMT 2015 armv7l

The programs included with the Debian GNU/Linux system are free software;
the exact distribution terms for each program are described in the
individual files in /usr/share/doc/*/copyright.

Debian GNU/Linux comes with ABSOLUTELY NO WARRANTY, to the extent
permitted by applicable law.
Last login: Sat Mar 21 13:25:48 2015 from 192.168.10.1
-bash: warning: setlocale: LC_ALL: cannot change locale (en_US.UTF-8)
-bash: warning: setlocale: LC_ALL: cannot change locale (en_US.UTF-8)
-bash: warning: setlocale: LC_ALL: cannot change locale (en_US.UTF-8)
```

Needless to say, when I try to do an "apt-get upgrade" or try to install a new application in my raspberry, I got errors relating to language. That's why I started looking for the solution... Could you please help me? I would be grateful!

Some additional informations:

When I type "locale" on my raspberry I got the following messages:

```
pi@raspberrypi ~ $ locale
locale: Cannot set LC_CTYPE to default locale: No such file or directory
locale: Cannot set LC_MESSAGES to default locale: No such file or directory
locale: Cannot set LC_ALL to default locale: No such file or directory
LANG=en_US.UTF-8
LANGUAGE=
LC_CTYPE="en_US.UTF-8"
LC_NUMERIC="en_US.UTF-8"
LC_TIME="en_US.UTF-8"
LC_COLLATE="en_US.UTF-8"
LC_MONETARY="en_US.UTF-8"
LC_MESSAGES="en_US.UTF-8"
LC_PAPER="en_US.UTF-8"
LC_NAME="en_US.UTF-8"
LC_ADDRESS="en_US.UTF-8"
LC_TELEPHONE="en_US.UTF-8"
LC_MEASUREMENT="en_US.UTF-8"
LC_IDENTIFICATION="en_US.UTF-8"
LC_ALL=en_US.UTF-8
```

If I write the same command on my laptop(I want to connect to rasberry from this laptop using ssh):

```
mirind4@mirind4-pc:~$ locale
LANG=en_US.UTF-8
LANGUAGE=en_US
LC_CTYPE="en_US.UTF-8"
LC_NUMERIC=de_DE.UTF-8
LC_TIME=de_DE.UTF-8
LC_COLLATE="en_US.UTF-8"
LC_MONETARY=de_DE.UTF-8
LC_MESSAGES="en_US.UTF-8"
LC_PAPER=de_DE.UTF-8
LC_NAME=de_DE.UTF-8
LC_ADDRESS=de_DE.UTF-8
LC_TELEPHONE=de_DE.UTF-8
LC_MEASUREMENT=de_DE.UTF-8
LC_IDENTIFICATION=de_DE.UTF-8
LC_ALL=
```

Thanks in advance!

Comment: Did you try "export LC_ALL=XX" ?

Comment: Crossposting: http://askubuntu.com/q/599532/336375

Answer (score 0):

Something in your environment is setting `LC_ALL=en_US.UTF-8`.  It's sufficient to only have `LANG=en_US.UTF-8` via `/etc/locale.conf`.